# Using KeyForge API with Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to call the KeyForge API with a simple Perl program but it doesn't work. I'm using what's in the LWP::UserAgent documentation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent ();

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->get('https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

The program prints:

> 500 write failed:  at test.pl line 16.

If I use the URL https://www.google.com or http://www.example.com, it works. The HTML is correctly displayed.

If I use this simple PowerShell program, it works too:

```
$Url = "https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/"
$decks = Invoke-RestMethod ($url)
$decks
```

It displays:

> count data
>
> ---
>
> 743719 {@{name=Dr. "The Old" Jeffries; expansion=341; power_level=0; chains=0; wins=0; losses=0; id=ec86db52-e41e-4e...

What am I missing?

PS: I'm using Perl 5.16.3 on Windows 10.

---

***EDIT:***
Thank you all for your help. I finally found out what was happening. It turns out I had a very old version of Net::HTTP (from 2013). I upgraded it and now it works out of the box, without configuring agent, cookies or e-mail. The error message I had was actually from the client and not from the server.

Comment: It works for me if I add an agent, for example: `$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');`

Comment: On Linux: without user agent I get `403 Forbidden`; with user agent I get `Content-Type: application/json` with a JSON body. Maybe you forgot to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https)? It is not included in the default libwww-perl distro.

Comment: You can test if it is installed with `perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -e 1`.

Comment: Without `LWP::Protocol::https` installed I get `501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported`. So no-one can reproduce your `500` response. I guess we need more details.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ perl -MLWP::UserAgent -e'
   my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
   my $response = $ua->get("https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/");
   print $response->as_string;
'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
...
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
...

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<title>Access denied | www.keyforgegame.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
...
            <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (www.keyforgegame.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (4bfe0c0e2e86ab84-ua22).</p>
...
```

But,

```
$ perl -MLWP::UserAgent -e'
   use version; our $VERSION = qv("v1.0.0");
   my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
      agent => "NameOfTool/$VERSION",
      from  => q{me@example.com},
   );
   my $response = $ua->get("https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/");
   print $response->as_string;
'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: application/json
...

{"count":...
```

If they want to block you, they can. So it's your best interest to provide a unique application name, a proper version and a valid email address (even if providing junk for the `agent` and leaving out `from` field works). This gives them more options to resolve any issues they have with your program.